Error 404 wp-admin/admin-ajax.php when submit wpform
I have a wordpress site deployed http://54.87.179.161/contact-us/ when i press submit buton on browser console it give me error
jquery.min.js?ver=3.7.1:2
    POST http://54.87.179.161/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 404 (Not Found)`

I am using apache2 as a webserver to serve the site and using wpforms for this form and integrate mailgun with it https://wpforms.com/ this one
Thanks in advance
please help me how I can resolve this error.

If you have the whole WP in /contact-us/, then this should probably be /contact-us/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php as well then. Assuming the plugin takes the correct steps to determine the admin-ajax URL dynamically, the error is probably somewhere in your configuration/setup then.

My whole wordpress code is in /var/www/html directory.

File system isn't all that relevant here. Question is, what is the root URL of your WP, is it http://54.87.179.161/contact-us/, or just http://54.87.179.161/

http://54.87.179.161/ Just this is the main url

And you can enter http://54.87.179.161/wp-admin/ to get to your WP admin area?

yes on loacalhost I use http://localhost/cyberoide/wp-admin/ but on deployment server wp-admin is not avaliable.

Why is it "not available"? And what exactly does that mean?

I created a build of my website and deploy it on the server

Then you will have to make it available, at least the admin-ajax script.

I created a build using "Simple Static the static site generator" this plugin.and do to this  the admin panel is not accessible.

Do you know anyother way to make a build of this.

You want dynamic functionality, so you can't really use a "static site". (Unless that plugin gave you any options, to keep part of the dynamic functionality somehow.)

Can you please suggest any plugin or way to make it possible

Just stop deploying this as a "static site" altogether, and use it as a "normal" WP ...?
